# DB2 tablespace space issue

Tags: db2

I have created db2 db with default space 4k,now my application is throwing space issue

SQLCODE: -1585, SQLSTATE: 54048, SQLERRMC: null
no sufficient space allocated for temp tablespace 
how to overcome this

can any one help on this.

Comment: I suggest you read the error message more carefully. It actually says "A system temporary table space with sufficient page size does not exist."

Answer (score 0):

DB2 has different type of tablespaces

- Regular (data, your default TableSpace)
- Large (data with long rows)
- Catalog (metadata)
- User temporary (for temporary tables)
- System temporary (for internal operations like sorts, joins, etc that sometimes overflows the memory)

You just need to create a system temporary table in the database to perform the operation you are trying to do. It is highly recommended to create temporary tablespaces (user and system) like SMS type, or automatic type for recent versions. Make sure the pagesize is the correct one.